# Apache service suddenly went down

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have Tomcat server installed on a Windows 7 machine.
Recently I have installed Xampp server on this same machine and everything was working well.
Suddenly, The Apache service went down and could't be started from the Xampp Control Panel and after some investigation I found out that the application that is using the Tomcat server was using port 80 and this prevented Apache from starting.

Kindly I need to understand why Apache suddenly went down? why it worked in parallel with the other application after it has been installed.
Has somebody encountered such an issue?

Your help is greatly appreciated,
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change port of Tomcat from port 80 to something other like default is port 8080 which needs to be defined in server.xml of Tomcat application